# How to show URLs in a bibliography as (hyperlinked) stubs?

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, urls

```
\label{References}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\lhead{\emph{References}}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{Bibliography}
```

I want to have all urls in my references list to be hyperlinked say under the word "URL". I've 100+ urls and its not looking very nice. I'm using BibTeX; so far, `abbrvnat` is the best style that has worked for me.

I'm using a template, hyperref is working fine. (I can hyper jump within the document.)
Any quick solution, i.e. not having to do this manually with each bib entry?

Comment: Have you tried \url{..,}?  Or possibly \string\url

Comment: Sorry, what's that??

Comment: A command from hyperref which links to urls

Comment: With `biblatex` (i just removed the tag) this would be the default. It is modern and flexible. If you have the choice, choose the modern system.

Comment: @Mico Apologies, I'm a newbie, I think am using BibTex.. Am using the third option on here http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/theses (Masters/Doctoral Theses)

Comment: @Johannes_B What Tag?

Comment: Tags help to sort questions by topic and keep the place clean. Also, people can filter for their favourite topics.

Comment: I wanted to add more tags... I couldn't because I'm new (dont have enough points)!

Comment: Are you asking how to mask the actual URL strings and just show a clickable stub?

Comment: Yes exactly, I thought that's what hyperlink is. A clickable URL word leads to the actual url I've in the entry without showing the URL strings...

Comment: 1. 99% of the time the reader will be online and reading an electronic version. 2. URL strings add nothing much to the reader's knowledge, he can read other details.

Answer (score 3):

The following solution operates only on the contents of `url` fields. URLs given in other fields are not treated. Since hyperlinking is being performed, the `hyperref` package must be loaded.

- Find the file `abbrvnat.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file, naming the copy (say) `myabbrvnat.bst`. (Don't edit directly an original file from your TeX distribution.)
- Open `myabbrvnat.bst` in a text editor. (The editor you use for your tex files will do fine.)
- Locate the function `format.url`. In my copy of the file, the function starts on line 306.
- In this function, replace the line

  ```
  { new.block "URL \url{" url * "}" * }
  ```

  with

  ```
  { new.block "\href{" url * "}{URL}" * }
  ```
- Save the file `myabbrvnat.bst`, either in the directory where your main tex file is located, or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter method, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution.
- Start using the new bibliography style by specifying it as the argument of the `\bibliographystyle` instruction. Be sure to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to propagate all changes.

In the pdf file version of the screenshot shown below, the blue "URL" stub is a hyperlink to this question.

[image]

The files `main.tex` and `main.bib` that generated this screenshot are as follows:

`main.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{myabbrvnat}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{main}
\end{document}
```

`main.bib`

```
@misc{xyz,
  author = "User70997",
  title  = "How to show {URLs} in a bibliography as (hyperlinked) stubs?",
  year   = 2015,
  month  = "January",
  url    = "http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224403/5001",
}
```

Comment: Please uncomment package `filecontents`. Too many users have overwritten their files for a lack of knowledgement. btw: the stub really looks odd ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B - Did you mean "comment out" instead of "uncomment"? Please advise. btw: I agree that the stub takes some getting used to.

Comment: Yes, i meant comment out. It's late ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B - Done.

Answer (score -1):

Personally I like the formatting style of the book class. So here would be an example to add a hyperlink to this citation, by using the note parameter of the book class, simply inserting a \href{...} command

Main document

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref} %Make hyperlinks available
\usepackage{cite}     %BibTeX support for bibliography and citing

\begin{document}

%An example citation
How to hyperlink all Bibliography URLs? It's easy \cite{Stack}.

\bibliography{bibl}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

bibl.bib file

```
@book{Stack,
  title     = "How to hyperlink all Bibliography URLs?",
  author    = "stackexchange",
  publisher = "stackexchange",
  year      = "2015",
  note      = "\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224403/how-to-hyperlink-all-bibliography-urls}{link-text}"
```

}

Comment: note      = "\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224403/how-to-hyperlink-all-bibliography-urls}{link-text}"

Comment: This means I have to do it manually for each entry??? Sorry man that's just too difficult to do when I have 200 urls already!

Comment: This answer disregards the information that the OP uses the bibliography style `abbrvnat` and, most likely, that `natbib` citation management package (and thus, likely, does *not* use the `cite` package).

Comment: to user70997: its a quick job with grep magic ;-) To Mico: There was no information about the citation management package, so I couldn't know that, what I was showing is a quick and easy way to insert a url using the note field, which should be applyable in any bibliography style